# Adding HTML attributes to an input component when using a custom field constructor

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am following the official [Java Form Helpers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaFormHelpers) documentation to write my own field constructor.  I have also drawn upon the `computer-database` sample application included with Play.

The template for the input control included in the `computer-database` sample application looks like this:

```
<div class="clearfix @if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
  <label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
  <div class="input">
      @elements.input
      <span class="help-inline">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

From this example, it's obvious how to add additional elements around the `<input>` element.  My problem is that I want to alter part of the `<input ...>` element itself.

I can't see how to do this because `@elements.input` renders the complete `<input type="..." value="..." ...>` HTML element, and so I have no opportunity to add additional attributes to the `input` element.

What I want to do is add `placeholder="my placeholder text"`. I want to get the placeholder text from `elements.args`.

I have been able to achieve what I want by doing string manipulation on the `@elements.input.buffer`, like so:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)
@{
  val buffer = elements.input.buffer;

  val index = buffer.lastIndexOf(">");     // find the closing '>'
  buffer.delete(index, buffer.length - 1); // delete it

  buffer ++= " placeholder=\""             // insert the placeholder attribute
  buffer ++= elements.args('placeholder).toString 
  buffer ++= "\">"                         // close the input tag

  Html(buffer.toString)                    // render as HTML
}
```

My question though is: is there a simpler way?  It there a facility for this already built into Play? Or is this my only avenue for adjusting the `input` field itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already built in and will work with your custom field constructors. It's actually documented under the **Rendering an <input> element** on the page you linked to.

> **Note:** All extra parameters will be added to the generated HTML, except for ones whose name starts with the _ character. Arguments starting with an underscore are reserved for field constructor argument (which we will see later).

So doing something like this:

```
@inputText(
  myForm("user"),
  '_label -> "User",
  'size -> 30,
  'placeholder -> "User Name"
)
```

Will output HTML like this:

```
<input id="user" name="user" size="30" placeholder="User Name">
```

It's documented somewhere, but if you want to do `data` attributes then you have to do this:

```
@inputText(
   ...
   Symbol("data-some-attribute") -> "value"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Situation where I needed to Add a `class` attribute to the field constructor to apply to all fields

```
     @inputText(engineForm("accessLevel"), '_label -> "access Level", 'class->"form-control")
@inputText(engineForm("logoURL"), '_label -> "Channel Logo", 'class->"form-control")
```

As you can see I had to add class Attribute to every field definition
 what I did In field constructor:

```
  @(elements: helper.FieldElements)

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="@elements.id" class="control-label col-lg-4">@elements.label</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                            @Html(elements.input.body.dropRight(2)+"class='form-control'>")

                    </div>
                  </div>
```

this will make you avoid adding the class attribute to every field

Comment: Although this is not the most elegant solution, it has the advantage of not requiring an additional parameter to each and for each every call to a helper (say for example if you are trying to make every field in a form readonly).